# Why the main thread is not in sequence in Swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I have the below function in SwiftUI. The JSON is parsing the right data but the order is : P1, P2, P5, P6, P3 & P4.  I need P1,P2,P3,P4,P5 & P6.Could someone help me I don't understand why is not following the logical thread.

```
    
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button ("Action", action: { self.checkLogin(username:"test", password:"123456") } )
 }

func checkLogin (username: String, password: String) {
    var body: [String:String] = [:]
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://test/apple/login.php") else { return  }
    body = ["user": username, "password": password]
    let finalBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode (body)
    print("final",body)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    print("p1")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = finalBody
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    print("p2")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
        print("p3")
        if let error = error { print ("Error: \(error)")
                               return
           }
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            print("p4")
            let finalData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ServerMessage.self, from: data)
            print (finalData)
           }
    }
    print ("p5")
        task.resume()
    print ("p6")
        return
}
}
struct ServerMessage: Decodable {
    let result: String
    let nuser: String
}
```

Comment: Read somewhere about asynchronous flow (programming) concept, eg. https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f.

Answer (score 0):

The URLSession that you created has a function called dataTask which executes on a background thread:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
        print("p3")
        if let error = error { print ("Error: \(error)")
                               return
           }
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            print("p4")
            let finalData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ServerMessage.self, from: data)
            print (finalData)
           }
    }
```

It will not get executed until you call task.resume(), this is the reason

```
print("p5")
```

was called first and will register the log on your console.

And when task.resume() is called, it does so in another thread making the execution asynchronous to the main thread.  Which means the main thread will move on to immediately execute

```
print ("p6")
```

Around the same time the background thread is implementing 'task': executing request and waiting for a response.  Once there is a response, this will execute:

```
print("p3")
```

If there is no error in the request,

```
print("p4")
```

will execute, if there is an error in the response's data, you will not see "p4" print out on the console because you guarded against it.

To guarantee that you get the order result that you wanted, you must put the print calls within the completion handler for that API

```
 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
        print("p3")
     
        if let error = error { 
              print ("Error: \(error)")
              return
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {  
            let finalData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ServerMessage.self, from: data)
            print (finalData)
            // Here is where you put non-UI code after you get a successful            
            // response and will guarantee that you get your data first
            print("p4")


           // Also keep in mind that since this is a background thread,           
           // you need to call the main thread in order to make your UI changes 
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  // All your UI changes here, so they will run on the main thread
                  print("p5")
                  print("p6")
            }
         }
         catch {
                 print("Error parsing data")
         }
    }
    task.resume() 
    return
}
```

Apple deprecated synchronous request API that you can do with NSURLConnection before, see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnection/1411393-sendsynchronousrequest?language=objc

This is because an unresponsive app is not something users will appreciate. Having a network call blocking the main thread will do just that.

You can read more about closures here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Comment: @EduardoMartinez You don't need to run the task on the main thread and you don't need the order P1-P6. You need to understand how asynchronous data processing works.

Comment: After some digging, I found out that Apple deprecated synchronous request for a reason, see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnection/1411393-sendsynchronousrequest?language=objc

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect this.  Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks  a lot Joanna. I am rellay new in swiftui. For a logging screen I need a function to validate if the user is registered. How coul I do it ? I need the server answer before to give acces or not. Please, any clue?

Comment: Hey @EduardoMartinez,I have revised my answer to illustrate where to best put your code to achieve the order that you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Joana, Thanks a lot. You gave me the 90% of the solution.

Comment: You're welcome!  It would be great if you can post the answer that you were looking for so that others can benefit from your findings.